# See what friends and followed people are playing with Spotify API

Tags: spotify

The spotify client lets you see friends or people you follow are playing. Is it possible to do that with the API? I looked through the whole [API Reference](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/) but couldn't find anything.

In the spotify client this is under "recent activity".

Comment: make a `POST` request to `https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/find-friends/v1/friends` & `GET` request to `https://guc-spclient.spotify.com/presence-view/v1/buddylist` using [this](https://github.com/valeriangalliat/spotify-buddylist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not currently available with the Spotify Web API. There is already an existing [feature request](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/12) about this issue on [Spotify Web API Issue Tracker Github page.](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/) Feel free to +1 there :)

Answer (score 0):

No public API to do this, but...

If you MITM your Spotify app you can observe the requests to `https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/presence-view/v1/buddylist` as well as your authentication token.  From there you can just hit this automatically. If you use Charles you can just click "copy request as cURL" and it's super easy.

Of course you need the app's auth token, so this only works for you and not for a 3rd party app that other people authorize too.  (at least, not without a lot more work)